# Can you reference a spark instance within a custom python package you import into a databricks notebook?

Tags: python, apache-spark, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, databricks

I want to create a custom connector class in a python package that I import into a databricks notebook. Something like:

```
class snowflake_read():
    
    def __init__(self, format, options):
        self.options = options
        self.format = format


    def sf_query(self, query):
        df = spark.read.format(self.format).options(self.options).options("query", query).load()
        return df
```

While I am able to import the package into the notebook and initialize the snowflake_read() class, I am not able to use the sf_query() function as spark is undefined.

```
import read_package

sf_read = snowflake_read(<format>, <options>)
sf_read.sf_query('<query>')
```

This code produces an undefined variable ('spark') error.

How do I define spark within the init function? Spark is automatically defined/initialized within the datbricks notebook but clearly isn't within the scope of the imported class.

Answer (score 1):

`spark` is automatically defined only in the notebooks directly, but not in the packages. You either need to pass that instance explicitly as a function parameter, or inside the function add following before calling the `spark.read` (import could be put outside of the function):

```py
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
spark = SparkSession.getActiveSession()
```

See [documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.2.1/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.SparkSession.getActiveSession.html#pyspark.sql.SparkSession.getActiveSession) for `SparkSession.getActiveSession` function.